# How can I get the mouse wheel to work correctly with the Silverlight 4 ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight

When I use the following xaml in Silverlight 4, the ScrollViewer will not recognize the mouse wheel unless I click once on the scroll bar thumb, and keep the mouse over the scroll bar, while turning the mouse wheel.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1">
            <Button Content="Button 1" Width="150" />
            <Button Content="Button 2" Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <Button Content="Button 3" Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <Button Content="Button 4" Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <Button Content="Button 5" Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <Button Content="Button 6" Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <Button Content="Button 7" Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Has anyone else experience this, and is there any work around?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The resolution here seems to be set a background brush on the ScrollViewer. In my case I chose to use the Transparent brush. It seems to be related to hit testing whereby a control without a brush will never receive any mouse events.

```
<ScrollViewer Background="Transparent">
```

Comment: +1: An alpha level of 0% (full transparency) on a Silverlight object takes it out of Hit-Testing. I am guessing the defined colour Transparent has an alpha value just above 0. I normally just set a colour with a 1% alpha, but will try "Transparent" instead now. Cheers

Comment: +1 Life Saver.  Was having this exact issue and couldn't figure it out.  It worked when the Scroll Viewer's child control was a custom control (With a Background Set) but when it was a stack panel without a background set it was failing.

Comment: +100000000 (if I could) I've been trying to get this to work for days.  Implementing custom scroll classes, swapping out different elements, etc.  It's always something so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Silverlight toolkit from here http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Add reference to the **System.Windows.Controls.Navigation** and **System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit** dlls

Modify your code to add the navigation namespace to the UserControl tag as shown below

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
```

Wrap your StackPanel in frame tag like so

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="SV"  >
        <navigation:Frame>
            <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1">
            <Button Content="Button 1" Width="150" />
```

In the code behind, add the following lines

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SV.SetIsMouseWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Reference : http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/mouse-wheel-scroll-for-scrollviewer-in-silverlight-3/

Comment: SetIsMouseWheelScrollingEnabled works, but only when the ScrollViewer contains a Frame element. I've tried a few other elements, but none of them seem to work with this hack. If anyone's interested in following this I've logged a connect bug report at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565397/mouse-wheel-does-not-work-correctly-with-the-silverlight-4-scrollviewer

Comment: While this hack works at run time it's not supported by either the VS2010 or Blend designers. When the view is opened in the designer all you'll see is the text "Frame", although resetting the Content property in Blend and doing an undo will make the content visible again.